How to serve recursive Many-to-Many relation with async SQLAlchemy on Strawberry Graphql
I made "Class" type and "User" type that have many-to-many relation. I want to return User info but I get the following error:

"sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet) greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?"

This is my query:
query User {
    user(userId: "d6144abfa0964467a8c4d572b83eb3ec") {
        id
        email
        name
        userType
        grade
        school
        phone
        parentPhone
        profileImage
        hasProfileImage
        classes {
            id
            name
        }
    }
}

In GraphQL
type User {
    id: String!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    userType: UserType!
    school: String
    grade: Grade
    phone: String
    parentPhone: String
    profileImage: String
    hasProfileImage: Boolean
    users: [User]!
}

type Class {
    id: Int!,
    name: String!,
    students: [User]!
}

And this is my python code
@strawberry.type(description="Class type")
class Class:
    id: int = strawberry.field(description="Class ID(Auto Increment)")
    name: str
    students: list[Annotated["User", strawberry.lazy("graphql_route.user")]] = strawberry.field(description="Student list")

    def __init__(self, class_info: ClassInfo):
        self.id = class_info.id
        self.name = class_info.name
        self.students = [User(student) for student in class_info.students]

@strawberry.type
class User:
    id: str = strawberry.field(description="User UUID(128-bit hex string)")
    email: str
    name: str
    userType: UserType
    grade: Grade | None
    school: str | None
    grade: int | None
    phone: str | None
    parentPhone: str | None
    profileImage: str | None = strawberry.field(description="Profile image URL")
    hasProfileImage: bool = strawberry.field(description="Whether the user has a profile image")
    classes: typing.List['Class'] = strawberry.field(description="Class list")

    def __init__(self, user_info: db_models.UserInfo):
        print(user_info.id)
        self.id = binascii.b2a_hex(user_info.id).decode()
        self.email = user_info.email
        self.name = user_info.name
        self.userType = UserType(user_info.user_type)
        self.school = user_info.school
        self.grade = Grade(user_info.grade) if user_info.grade else None
        self.phone = user_info.phone
        self.parentPhone = user_info.parent_phone
        self.profileImage = user_info.profile_image
        self.hasProfileImage = bool(user_info.profile_image)
        self.classes = [Class(class_info) for class_info in user_info.classes]

@strawberry.type
class Query:
    @strawberry.field(name="user", description="Get a single user", permission_classes=[AssistantPermission])
    async def single_user(self, info: Info, user_id: str) -> User | None:
        session: AsyncSession = info.context.db
        user_info = await session.execute(
            select(db_models.UserInfo).where(db_models.UserInfo.id == binascii.a2b_hex(user_id)))
        user_info = user_info.scalar()
        return User(user_info=user_info) if user_info else None

This is Error Message
  File "D:\Programming\kweb\api\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 122, in await_only
    raise exc.MissingGreenlet(
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet) greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?
[SQL: SELECT userinfo.id AS userinfo_id, userinfo.email AS userinfo_email, userinfo.name AS userinfo_name, userinfo.school AS userinfo_school, userinfo.grade AS userinfo_grade, userinfo.phone AS userinfo_phone, userinfo.parent_phone AS userinfo_parent_phone, userinfo.profile_image AS userinfo_profile_image, userinfo.user_type AS userinfo_user_type 
FROM userinfo, userinfo_classinfo 
WHERE %s = userinfo_classinfo.class_id AND userinfo.id = userinfo_classinfo.user_id]
[parameters: [{'%(2011849031856 param)s': 1}]]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:ROLLBACK

This is Sqlalchemy log
INFO:     Started server process [28608]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8001 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT DATABASE()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[raw sql] ()
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Col ('DATABASE()',)
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Row ('kweb',)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT @@sql_mode
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[raw sql] ()
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Col ('@@sql_mode',)
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Row ('STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT @@lower_case_table_names
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[raw sql] ()
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Col ('@@lower_case_table_names',)
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Row (0,)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT userinfo.id, userinfo.email, userinfo.name, userinfo.school, userinfo.grade, userinfo.phone, userinfo.parent_phone, userinfo.profile_image, userinfo.user_type 
FROM userinfo 
WHERE userinfo.id = %s
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00012s] (b'\xd6\x14J\xbf\xa0\x96Dg\xa8\xc4\xd5r\xb8>\xb3\xec',)
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Col ('id', 'email', 'name', 'school', 'grade', 'phone', 'parent_phone', 'profile_image', 'user_type')
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Row (b'\xd6\x14J\xbf\xa0\x96Dg\xa8\xc4\xd5r\xb8>\xb3\xec', 'm', 'h', None, None, None, None, 'https', 0)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT userinfo_1.id AS userinfo_1_id, classinfo.id AS classinfo_id, classinfo.name AS classinfo_name 
FROM userinfo AS userinfo_1 INNER JOIN userinfo_classinfo AS userinfo_classinfo_1 ON userinfo_1.id = userinfo_classinfo_1.user_id INNER JOIN classinfo ON classinfo.id = userinfo_classinfo_1.class_id 
WHERE userinfo_1.id IN (%s)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00013s] (b'\xd6\x14J\xbf\xa0\x96Dg\xa8\xc4\xd5r\xb8>\xb3\xec',)
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Col ('userinfo_1_id', 'classinfo_id', 'classinfo_name')
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Row (b'\xd6\x14J\xbf\xa0\x96Dg\xa8\xc4\xd5r\xb8>\xb3\xec', 1, 'test class')
ERROR:strawberry.execution:(sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet) greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?
[SQL: SELECT userinfo.id AS userinfo_id, userinfo.email AS userinfo_email, userinfo.name AS userinfo_name, userinfo.school AS userinfo_school, userinfo.grade AS userinfo_grade, userinfo.phone AS userinfo_phone, userinfo.parent_phone AS userinfo_parent_phone, userinfo.profile_image AS userinfo_profile_image, userinfo.user_type AS userinfo_user_type 
FROM userinfo, userinfo_classinfo 
WHERE %s = userinfo_classinfo.class_id AND userinfo.id = userinfo_classinfo.user_id]
[parameters: [{'%(2011849031856 param)s': 1}]]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)

I tried change sqlalchemy relationship lazy to selectin, joined and subquery
